# Kotlin: gson conversion "Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class"

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting the following error `Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class Entry. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.`

My code extends an Entry class.

```
abstract class Data : ArrayList<Entry>() {

//code removed for simplicity

    abstract class Entry(str: String) {
        open var name: String = str
    }
}

class Category: Data() {
    class CategoryItem(
        override var name: String
    ) : Entry(name)
}
```

I have a handler class to handle the transaction.

```
class JsonHelper(private var type: KClass<Category>) {
    private val json = Gson()
    private var contents: String? = null
    private var data: Any? = null

    fun convert(string: String): Any? {
        data = json.fromJson(string, type.java)
        return data
    }
}
```

I call

```
json = JsonHelper(Category::class)
json.convert(file.read())
//file.read() comes from a file as a string, this works as intended
```

previously I had it setup where Entry was just an empty class and I added the name field while debugging, but it had no effect.
I have searched on stackoverflow and haven't found anything that would help, except that you shouldn't use suspend to call it, which you can see im not.

I have also tried using a `TypeToken` which I would pass into `json.fromJson(string, type)` at runtime, this also didn't help.

```
private var type = object: TypeToken<Category>(){}.type
```

Any Ideas? I would like gson to return a Category type class to me.

Comment: Try assign a default value to each parameter

Comment: I tired, it didn't work. should I have done it in the abstract class declaration? `abstract class Entry(str: String = "")`

Comment: Add constructor with no input parameter to `Entry` and `CategoryItems` classes.

Comment: didn't work, is this correct? `abstract class Entry(str: String = "") {
    open var name: String = str

    fun Entry() {}
}` and `class CategoryItem(
        override var name: String
    ) : Entry(name) {
        fun CategoryItem() {}
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `Category` extends `ArrayList<Entry>`, so GSON needs to know how to instantiate an `Entry` and it can't because it's abstract.

*If* the intention is that a `Category` should only contain `CategoryItem`, not arbitrary `Entry`, it should be

```
abstract class Data<T : Entry> : ArrayList<T>() {

    abstract class Entry(str: String) {
        open var name: String = str
    }
}

class Category: Data<CategoryItem>() {
    class CategoryItem(
        override var name: String = ""
    ) : Entry(name)
}
```

Extending `ArrayList` instead of having a field of that type is also not usually a good idea.

Comment: This was helpful but it didn't exactly fix the problem, as i had other errors pop up. For now I think you are right, I should refactor my code so that I have a field with an `ArrayList` instead.